# How to create a series of jquery/js animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, particles

I'm a bit of a noob with js but have messed around with http://scurker.com/blog/2010/06/particle-generator-using-html5s-canvas and came up with

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://scurker.com/projects/particles/js/particle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://scurker.com/projects/particles/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://scurker.com/projects/particles/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

var particles;
window.onload = function() {  
  var canvas = document.getElementById('particle_canvas');
  particles = new ParticleCanvas(canvas, {x: 470});
 };

var effects = { 

  blue: {
    shape: 'circle',
    velocity: new Vector({y: -0.35}),
    color: '#0000ff',
    opacity: 1,
    onDraw: function(p) {
      p.opacity = 0.251 - (p.age / p.life) * 0.25;
    }
  },

  red: {
    shape: 'circle',
    velocity: new Vector({y: -3}),
    color: '#ff0000',
    opacity: 1,
    onDraw: function(p) {
      var y = -this.age * 3;
      p.size *= 0.98;
      p.opacity = 0.5 - (p.age / p.life * 0.4);
    }
  },
};

$.fn.toJson = function() {
  var json = {};
  $.each(this.serializeArray(), function() {
    json[this.name] = this.value !== null ? this.value : null;
  });
  return json;
};

function loadPreset(val) {
  var obj;  
  if((obj = effects[val])) {
    particles.update(obj);
    for(var i in obj) {
      var value = (obj[i] instanceof Vector) ? -obj[i].y : obj[i];
      $(':input[name=' + i + ']').val(value);
    }
    $('input').change();
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#controls :input').change(function() {
    particles.update($('#controls :input').toJson());
 particles.start();
  });

  $('select').change(function() { loadPreset(this.value); });
});

  </script>
</head>
     <body>
         <div id="particle_container">
<div id="controls">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>Presets: 
        <select>
          <option value="blue">Blue</option>
          <option value="red">Red</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<canvas id="particle_canvas" height="500" width="940"></canvas>
```

I couldnt get it to work in jsfiddle but in a normal website it will create a drop down menu with the options red or blue.

When you select red some animated red partcles appear on the canvas, when you select blue from the list the particles turn blue.

What Im trying to do is remove the select list, which I know how to do.

But set the red/blue animations to be at time intervals.

So for example the page loads, wait 2 seconds then I want the red particles to be displayed for 5 seconds (as if a user has selected red from the drop down menu) then a pause for 2 seconds, and the blue particles to start for another 5 seconds (again as if somebody has selected blue from the drop down list).

So basically im trying to set the particles to run at preset intervals rather than being manually selected.

How would I acheive this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just use setTimeout in javascript?

```
setTimeout(/*do nothing*/,2000); // waiting
// red particles
setTimeout(/* Stop particles after 5 second*/,5000);
setTimeout(/*do nothing*/,2000); // waiting
// blue particles
setTimeout(/* Stop particles after 5 second*/,5000);
```